# Import DLL c++ on VSC# 2010 (AdminPaq SDK )

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to import a library to my WCF project, the DLL was provided by Adminpaq.

i'm using the next following code:

```
 [DllImport("MGW_SDK.dll", EntryPoint = "fInicializaSDK")]
public static extern int fInicializaSDK();
```

When i debug the app say the next error : Unable to load DLL The specified module could not be found.

I've ready on web that the error could be by dependece but on the SDK documentation display a list of some files that must be added to the root project i'm currently  adding al of them

Some info:
Dll is build on: c++
Proyect type: c# Application service MCF 
I'm using: Windows 7 ultimate x64

Any further information required please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Is the DLL in the same folder as the EXE?

Comment: yes, all SDK dependencies are added to the proyect, by the way i'm developing a Web services application so.. i don't know if for some security issues can't be ready. but i'm currently only testing via Debug of VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, usually it is related to some other library that your MGW_SDK.dll depends on. Try these:

1) Install the Microsoft Visual C++ redist (2005, 2008 or 2010, depending on which VS was used to build that dll)

2) If that does not help, try using dependency walker tool to see which files are missing (http://www.dependencywalker.com)

I hope that helps.

Comment: I've already use dependecy waker and send me some files at windows32 folder. it appears that applicacion is build for win32, un furtunately i didn't found dll on web. i'm gonna try the C++ redist for VS2010. let see if it works!

Comment: using dependency walker says that missing files are: BCBSMP50.BPL

VCL50.BPL
VCLBDE50.BPL
VCLDB50.BPL
VCLX50.BPL         Do you have any idea from where are those files?

Comment: thank you to all. i have already get this work. the solucion was add all those file to system vars..

Comment: Just as recommendation the best solution was to add all the required files to System Variables width a default folder for al dependencies in  C:/adminpaq

Comment: Can you help me? Not I can make connection with MGW_SDK.DLL

Answer (score 0):

You must type the full and original path of the DLL, for example: @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Compacw\AdminPAQ\MGW_SDK.dll"

Answer (score 0):

you must install AdminPaq and have a registered license, after that the error will dissapear